# Python request login is not working

Tags: java, python, request, mechanize

I am trying to post a request to log in to a website using the Requests module in Python but its not really working. I need to change stuff automaticaly in iomega home media network. Here is the login page. There must be something preventing the log in.

```
function SubmitForm() {
//first of all, check if the login field is not empty
if ($("#mnglogin").val() == "") {
    //present an error message about it
    showErrorStr("Nome de usuário ou senha especificado inválido.", function () {
        //focus the username field
        $("#mnglogin").focus();
        return (false);
    });

    return (false);
}

//do the login
var usernameValue;
usernameValue = $("#mnglogin").val();
var flds = addField(null, "login", usernameValue);

flds = addField(flds, "password", $("#mngpwd").val());
formPost("#folderLoginDialog", getRestUrl("SessionLogin"), flds,
    [{"api":"login","form":"mnglogin","text":"Nome de usuário"},
    {"api":"password","form":"mngpwd","text":"Senha"}],
    {after:loginDone,hideError:true});
return (false);
```

}

Comment: And where is your code using `requests` to log in? How is anyone supposed to see what's wrong with it?